# How can I delete an email address from Outlook's email history?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

When I type an email address in Outlook 2007 it keeps suggesting addresses that no longer are relevant for me. How can I delete an address that appears in the suggestion list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Highlight it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: just plain Delete works

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Office 2010 you can press on "X" flag in front of every address which will delete the email. If you have office 2003 or 2007 just highlight the address and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.